# Adding a pinned tab icon for Safari through Phoenix

Tags: html, svg, safari, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to add a pinned tab icon that is visible in Safari, like this:
[image: pinned tabs in safari]

I have found this instruction: [Apple's instruction for pinned tab icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/pinnedTabs/pinnedTabs.html)

However, when I use this construction in my app.html.eex like this:

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/website_icon.svg") %>" color="red" >
```

or

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/website_icon.svg") color="red" >
```

where the website_icon.svg is in the static root;

the page redirects me to localhost:4000/website_icon.svg, which is correct, but then shows a 404 error page as if it should have been pointed towards in the router.

So my question: How can I get Phoenix to get the mask-icon to display correctly, rather than getting a 404?

*NB: The favicon is displayed correctly without explicit coding, but also 404's when I explicitly code it into app.html.eex like the previous code examples.*

Comment: Are you clicking on anything, or is the page just redirecting the moment it loads? Because I have never seen the behaviour you describe.

Comment: When I don't see the mask-icon in Safari, I use "Inspect element" to find the <link> tag where the icon link is displayed. I click that, and get the 404 instead of an image. If it showed an image, it would mean the icon should be displayed in the browser tab.

Comment: Sounds like you either put the image in the wrong location, or you are calling the incorrect path.

Comment: I just checked whether I hadn't made a mistake like that, so I called favicon.ico the same way; and the favicon.ico does display in the browser. I called another .svg item and it presented a 404. It seems Phoenix cannot load .svg's by default?

Comment: I got it working. Apparently, all SVG's are supposed to be in the /assets/images folder, even when they're typically in the static root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `endpoint.ex` file, there is a line specifying what the static plug should handle. Mine looks like the following

```
plug Plug.Static,
  at: "/", from: :my_app, gzip: false,
  only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt)
```

You will want to either put your file in the images directory, or add a `website_icon.svg` similar to the `favicon.ico` entry.

Comment: An even better solution.